# Plotly treemap child nodes not scalling numerically

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

Hello all I have created a treemap which has 104 nodes these nodes are arranged numerically vertical correct till 92 node but after that it is converting to horizontal arrangement  from 93 to 104
[image]

I tried everything from changing height to width but it is not working

Comment: This is weird behavior. I looked into the [docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.treemap.html) and couldn't find anything. Regardless of the order the data appear in the dataframe, it seems the plotting algorithm Plotly uses randomly places some of the nodes. I don't know if there is a solution...

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is posting on https://community.plotly.com/ to see if you get some better insights or workarounds.

Comment: @russhoppa thank you for suggestion i will post it on plotly community